# How do I check if a type provides a parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constructor, types

I'd like to check if a type that is known at runtime provides a parameterless constructor. The `Type` class did not yield anything promising, so I'm assuming I have to use reflection?

Comment: Sidenote: There is a generic constraint for parameterless constructors.

Comment: is the question whether the type **only** provides a parameterless constructor or if it provides one at all?

Comment: The latter. I don't mind the presence of additional ctors.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The `Type` class *is* reflection. You can do:

```
Type theType = myobject.GetType(); // if you have an instance
// or
Type theType = typeof(MyObject); // if you know the type

var constructor = theType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
```

It will return null if a parameterless constructor does not exist.

---

If you also want to find private constructors, use the slightly longer:

```
var constructor = theType.GetConstructor(
  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
  null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
```

---

There's a caveat for value types, which [aren't allowed to have a default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208(VS.71).aspx). You can check if you have a value type using the [`Type.IsValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx) property, and create instances using [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx);

Answer (score 20):

```
type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
```

would fail for `struct`s. Better to extend it:

```
public static bool HasDefaultConstructor(this Type t)
{
    return t.IsValueType || t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null;
}
```

Succeeds since even `enum`s have default parameterless constructor. Also slightly speeds up for value types since the reflection call is not made.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you have to use Reflection. But you already do that when you use `GetType()`

Something like:

```
var t = x.GetType();
var c = t.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
if (c != null) ...
```

Comment: What does new "Type[0]" do? - It would be helpful to have that information inline.

Comment: It's an empty array of Types. Same as Type.EmptyTypes.

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
   myClass.GetType().GetConstructors()
                    .All(c=>c.GetParameters().Length == 0)
```

Comment: Not what I meant, but please don't delete - it's a related issue and a nice information.

Comment: Indeed, the correct expression for the OP's request should be `myClass.GetType().GetConstructors().Any(c=>c.GetParameters().Length == 0)`. Note the use of **Any** instead of **All**.

Comment: @GlennSlayden is correct. It should be .Any() instead of .All(). Otherwise the you will be checking if your type has only one constructor, that one constructor being parameter-less.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your situation, you could also use a generic type restriction:

```
public void DoSomethingWith<T>(T myObject) where T:new() {...}
```

The above method declaration will restrict the parameter type to any Object that can be instantiated with a parameterless constructor. The advantage here is that the compiler will catch any attempt to use the method with a class that doesn't have a parameterless constructor, so as long as the type is known SOMEWHERE at compile-time, this will work and will alert you to a problem earlier.

Of course if the type really is known only at runtime (i.e. you're using Activator.CreateInstance() to instantiate an object based on a string or a constructed Type) then this won't help you. I generally use reflection as the absolute last option, because once you've gone to dynamic land you pretty much have to stay in dynamic land; it's usually difficult or even messier to dynamically instantiate something and then start dealing with it statically.

Comment: Actually, there's a very useful pattern for bridging the lands of static and dynamic invocation: a static generic caching class [e.g. `EqualityComparer.Default<T>`].  For any given type `T`, one will only have to use Reflection once to build an object whose instance type will be statically known to qualify for any required constraints, and store a reference to it in a field that does not impose any constraints that a caller might not be able to supply.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to count constructors with *only* optional parameters the same as true parameter-less constructors.  To do this:

```
myClass.GetType().GetConstructors()
    .All(c => c.GetParameters().Length == 0 || c.GetParameters().All(p => p.IsOptional))
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is interested in an "official" version, the following was found via [.NET Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/):

from: **System.Activities.Presentation.TypeUtilities**
in **System.Activities.Presentation.dll, Version=4.0.0.0**

```
public static bool CanCreateInstanceUsingDefaultConstructor(this Type t) => 
                t.IsValueType || !t.IsAbstract && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null;
```

Notice the check for `t.IsAbstract`, which is not mentioned elsewhere on this page.

You can also expand the `GetConstructor` call out as follows, if you feel like micro-optimizing away one stack frame:

```
…t.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null)…
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use reflection.

```
object myObject = new MyType();
Type type = myObject.GetType();
ConstructorInfo conInfo = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the one that has more optional parameters or an empty constructor at all, use:

```
    typeof(myClass)
    .GetConstructors()
    .OrderBy(x => x.GetParameters().Length - x.GetParameters().Count(p => p.IsOptional))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```