# checking beforehand if `System.Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)` will fail

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a type (Human) and I want to know if I could do `System.Activator.CreateInstance(Of Human)()`. So basically I want to check if Human has a public parameterless constructor / or a public constructor with optional parameters that make it possible to call `New Human` without giving any arguments.

Is it possible to check beforehand if `System.Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)` will fail? (I mean other than wrapping the statement `System.Activator.CreateInstance(Of Human)()` in a Try Catch of course..)

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
Option Strict On : Option Explicit On
Module Test
    Public Class Human
        Public Sub New(Optional ByVal a As Integer = 1)

        End Sub
    End Class
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim c = GetType(Human).GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes)
        MsgBox(c Is Nothing)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Note, that this will not/never work out of the box for constructors "with only optional arguments". See my answer below for more details and background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a type provides a parameterless constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681031/how-do-i-check-if-a-type-provides-a-parameterless-constructor)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To check if the constructor is empty or all paramters are optional:

```
var hasEmptyOrDefaultConstr = 
  typeof(Human).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null || 
  typeof(Human).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Any (x => x.GetParameters().All (p => p.IsOptional));
```

Comment: this isn't working if I have a `Private sub new` he tells me its True. but if i do ` System.Activator.CreateInstance(Of Human)()` I will get an exception of course!

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer to exclude non public and static constructors

Comment: ok cool I've settled with this:         `Dim is_activatable = GetType(Human).GetConstructors(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public).Any(Function(c) c.GetParameters.All(Function(p) p.IsOptional))`

Comment: btw isn't it weird that there isn't a built in `IsActivatable` function ?

Comment: I can see how that would be useful.

Comment: +1: thanks. Like the LINQ query to check for a constructor with all arguments optional

Answer (score 4):

You can check and make sure your type `Human` has an accessible parameterless constructor. Easiest way to do is create a generic method and add a constraint `where T : new()`

EDIT:

You can manually check for parameterless constructor like this

```
if(typeof(Human).GetType().GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) !=null)
{
  ...      
}
```

Comment: I do know about that constraint where T:new() however I need T to support both types that have constraint `new()` and types that do not have that constraint

Comment: @Pacerier Optional parameters makes it tricky. But @Magnus answer addressed that area.

Comment: extra `GetType()` shouldn't be used as `typeof(Human)`  already gets the type. (or just use `GetType()` instead of `typeof()`)

Answer (score 3):

Please note, that `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` or `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)` will only work with parameterless constructors. A constructor with only optional arguments is *not* parameterless in that sense.

Optional parameters (or arguments) are resolved by the C# compiler *on the call site*. However, there is no compiler involved in such a way when invoking the constructor using reflection.

If you use the following code, you'll get a `MissingMethodException` saying that there is no parameterless constructor defined:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo(int optional = 42)
        {
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Activator.CreateInstance<Foo>(); // causes MissingMethodException
        }
    }
}
```

In other words optional arguments are a compiler thing, not a CLR thing.

For more information about "corner cases with optional arguments" see this recent blog series of Eric Lippert:

http://ericlippert.com/2011/05/09/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-one/

Having that said, you might be able to somehow replicate the desired behavior using some more reflection and manually creating the required parameters for the constructor call. The compiler will place some attributes inside the assembly which you could use for that purpose, I guess.

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo([Optional, DefaultParameterValue(5)] int optional)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructed");
    }
}
```

Comment: btw how do we translate your last paragraph into vb?

Comment: @Pacerier: I'm not quite sure what exactly you are referring to, but the attributes placed into the code by the compiler are the same for C# and VB.NET, i.e. both compilers seem to generate the same code in that respect.

Comment: @Christian.K I mean i don't know where to put the line **[Optional, DefaultParameterValue(5)]**. this doesn't compile for me:  Public Class Foo
        Public Sub New([Optional,DefaultParameterValue(5)]ByVal x As Integer)

        End Sub
    End Class

Comment: @Pacerier You don't put it there, that does your compiler (VB.NET or C#). You need to *read* them (using reflection). To stay in the spirit of the other answers you could do something like this: (1) figure out if you have a true parameterless constructor, if so, do as the others suggested. (2) if you have a constructor where all paramaters have default values (hence the attributes shown in the "Example" of my answer), you use reflection to get the values, and build a proper object[] to pass it to the Activator.CreateInstance-overload for non-parameterless constructors.

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick console app using reflection to test for parameter-less constructors on types. Is this what you need?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class HasPublicParameterlessContructorClass
    {
    }

    public class DoesntHavePublicParameterlessContructorClass
    {
        private int someField;

        public DoesntHavePublicParameterlessContructorClass(int someParameter)
        {
            someField = someParameter;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static bool HasPublicParameterlessContructor(Type t)
        {
            return t.GetConstructors().Any(constructorInfo => constructorInfo.GetParameters().Length == 0);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(HasPublicParameterlessContructor(typeof(HasPublicParameterlessContructorClass)));
            Console.WriteLine(HasPublicParameterlessContructor(typeof(DoesntHavePublicParameterlessContructorClass)));
        }
    }
}
```