# How to cast an object as having a public parameterless constructor to respect a : new() constraint?

Tags: c#, interface, casting, signature, type-constraints

Is it possible at all to check if a type has a parameterless constructor, in order to cast it and call a method which requires a parameterless constructor with the `: new()` constraint?

Being only able to only check that a type as a public parameterless as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681031/how-do-i-check-if-a-type-provides-a-parameterless-constructor) would not be enough as it would not allow calling the target methods.

The objective is to have the following logic, where `IInteresting` objects do not implement a public parameterless constructor and need to be converted before calling `Save1`:

```
    public interface IInteresting { }

    public void Save<T>(T o) {
        var oc = o as (new()); /* Pseudo implementation */
        if (oc != null) {
            this.Save1(oc);
        }
        else {
            var oi = o as IInteresting;
            if (oi != null) {
                this.Save2(oi);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Save1<T>(T o) where T : new() {
        //Stuff
    }

    private void Save2<T>(IInteresting o) {
        //Stuff to convert o to a DTO object with a public parameterless constructor, then call Save1(T o)
    }
```

Of course if I could make `Save1` and `Save2` share the same signature that would solve the issue, but I cannot find a way to do so as the following will not compile (in `Routine`, `Save` will call the first implementation instead of the second):

```
    public void Routine<T>(T o) {
        var oi = o as IInteresting;
        if (oi != null) {
            this.Save(oi);
        }
    }

    private void Save<T>(T o) where T : new() {
        //Stuff
    }

    private void Save<T>(IInteresting o) {
        //Stuff to convert o to a DTO object with a public parameterless constructor, then call Save(T o)
    }
```

Comment: "would not be enough as it would not allow calling the target methods." - actually, it would. [`ConstructorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo.aspx) has an [`Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17.aspx).

Comment: Just use reflection? But first, rethink your design.

Comment: What is inside your Save1<T> method?

Comment: The Save method is calling a ServiceStack.OrmLite function which requires an object of a type with a parameterless constructor. I need to convert the object to a DTO (respecting : new()) if it is not one already.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't think ConstructorInfo with its Invoke method would allow me to cast the original object (only create a new one), would it?

Comment: @ErwinMayer: The `ConstructorInfo.Invoke` method allows you to invoke the constructor - which is what I thought you wanted to do, based on your implicit wish of "calling the target methods". Of course, once you have verified that the type in question has a parameterless constructor, you can also use reflection to retrieve the `MethodInfo` of other methods and invoke those. (Though I wonder what bearing the presence or absence of a parameterless constructor could have unless you intend to call it, or have someone else call it.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This is a valid approach indeed, which provides a working solution, though I was hoping to avoid Reflection if possible.

Comment: @ErwinMayer All right, I've read the code in the question once more. The use case is quite strange, so I couldn't get it. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I imagine you have an object of an unknown type that you want to pass to a generic function that requires the passed-over object to be of the generic type argument, which has to have a parameterless constructor. Hence, for the time being, we can assume that your function `Save1<T>(T)` from your question is that function, not written by you, not possible to be changed.

A solution to this would be to make the call by using reflection:

- Find the [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) of the method you are trying to call by using [`Type.GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx).
- Construct the `MethodInfo` of the method for your parameterless-constructor-type by specifying type arguments with [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx).
- Invoke the method by calling the [`MethodInfo.Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx).

Comment: Wow that would do it indeed, though I was hoping for a more out of the box way to achieve this.

Comment: @ErwinMayer: As generics invariably - unless you use reflection - have to be resolved at compile-time, while you know your type only at runtime, I'm afraid there is no viable other way. The only slight simplification you could add to this solution is by using a generic class that itself invokes the generic method based on a non-generic method call - that way, you would skip the `GetMethod` step (which is based on the string-name of the method and thus not compiler-checked) and instead use `typeof(MyCallerType<>).MakeGenericType(o.GetType())`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, depending on what you do inside `private void Save<T>(T o) where T : new()` is to use [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interface. Or introduce yours (as I've said, it depends on `Save`'s contents):

```
interface IConstructible
{
    object Construct();
}
```

And have:

```
private void Save1<T>(T o) where T : ICloneable {
```

Of course this is just a workaround - [O. R. Mapper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19753686/2642204) gives the only direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Reflection;


public static class Generics {
 public static void T0<T> ( T obj ) where T : new () {
  Console.WriteLine ( "{0} {1}", obj, obj.GetType () );
 }

 public static void T1<T> ( T obj ) {
  MethodInfo mi = GenericMethodInfo ( typeof ( Generics ), "T0", typeof ( T ) );
  mi.Invoke ( null, new object[] { obj } );
 }

 public static MethodInfo GenericMethodInfo ( Type classType, string methodName, Type genericType ) {
  return classType.GetMethod ( methodName ).MakeGenericMethod ( genericType );
 }
}


Generics.T0 ( 123 );
Generics.T1 ( 123 );
// Impossible.. Generics.T0 ( "12345" );
Generics.T1 ( "12345" );
```

Comment: The best answers have some explanation as well as code. Please consider adding some context.