# Reflection: Initialize Object Issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, reflection

I added reference of one DLL in my project and was successfully able to access methods/classes of that DLL.

Code in DLL: (I do not have access to modify this code)

```
//Dll: myDllName
    Namespace myNamespace
        Public Class MyClass
                Private Sub New(ByVal parameter1 As Int64)
                    //Set some values
                End Sub

                Public Shared Function MyPublicFunction(ByVal Parameter1 As Int64,ByVal Parameter2 As INt64,ByVal Parameter2 As Int64) As MyClass
                Dim retMyClass As New MyClass(Parameter1)
                //Set Other Values

                Return retMyClass
          End Function

          Public Function Post() As Boolean
            //Do some operation
          End Function
        End Class
    End Namespace
```

My code where I have called above DLL:

```
Dim myObj As myDllName.myNamespace.MyClass
myObj = myDllName.myNamespace.MyClass.MyPublicFunction(Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3)

myObj.Prop1 = MyVal1
myObj.Prop2 = MyVal2
myObj.Prop3 = MyVal1
myObj.Post()
```

Now my requirement is I want to achieve above task without adding reference of DLL to the project.
So I tried to achieve this with reflection.

```
Dim assembly As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("..\\myDllName.dll")
Dim t As Type = assembly.GetType("myDllName.myNamespace.MyClass")
Dim woFacadeinst As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
```

But on object initialization it throws me error that Constructor on type

> myDllName.myNamespace.MyClass

not found.

I think it is because of the Private NEW method in my DLL reference class.
Can someone help with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a type provides a parameterless constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681031/how-do-i-check-if-a-type-provides-a-parameterless-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

For parameterized constructor use `GetConstructors()` and `Invoke()` instead of `Activator.CreateInstance()` as the following :

```
 Dim constructor = t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)

 Dim woFacadeinst As Object = constructor(0).Invoke(New Object() {5})
```

because it takes more time, check the graph in this [link](https://vagifabilov.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/dont-use-activator-createinstance-or-constructorinfo-invoke-use-compiled-lambda-expressions/)  and if the performance really matters for you try compiled lambda expressions, it is way faster than both.

Comment: Try this answer instead

Comment: Can you explain why he should not use the `Activator.CreateInstance()`

Comment: Thanks for the link and the clarification. May I have to adjust some code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are running into this exception, because with this line

```
Dim woFacadeinst As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
```

you try to call a parameter less constructor, which does not exist.

So you have to call `Activator.CreateInstance()` with some more parameters to pass the required parameter to the constructor.

```
Private Sub New(ByVal parameter1 As Int64)
    'Set some values
End Sub
```

Usually in C# I used the following snippet:

```
var woFacadeinst = Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(Class1), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,  
                                             null, new object[] { 5 }, null );
```

and as vb.Net:

```
Dim woFacadeinst As Object = Activator.CreateInstance( GetType(Class1),  
                                                       BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                       Nothing, New Object(){ 5 }, Nothing)
```

The trick to get the private constructor are the right [`Bindingflags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx)
and with `new object[]{ 5 }` you are setting the parameter(s) requied by the constructor.

---

**Hint:** *For performance concerns take a look at the [Ali Ezzat Odeh' Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46092842/5893316).*

If you want to use the `GetConstructor()` method you can do this like the following C# snippet:

```
 var test = typeof(Class1).GetConstructor( BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                            null, new Type[] { typeof(Int64) }, null )
                          ?.Invoke( new object[] { 64 } );
```

---

As C# Example:

**The Class:**

```
public class Class1
{
    private Class1(string myString)
    {
        MyIntProperty = 42;
        MyStringProperty = myString;
    }

    private Class1(int myInt)
    {
        MyIntProperty = myInt;
        MyStringProperty = "default";
    }

    private Class1(Int64 myInt64)
    {
        MyInt64Property = myInt64;
        MyStringProperty = "default";
    }

    public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
    public int MyIntProperty { get; set; }
    public Int64 MyInt64Property { get; set; }
}
```

and the **test snippet**:

```
string testString = "Test";
int testInt = 123;

var objArray = new object[1];

objArray[0] = testString;
var testClass1 = Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(Class1), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                           null, objArray, null );

objArray[0] = testInt;
var testClass2 = Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(Class1), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, 
                                           null, objArray, null );

var testCtorClass = typeof(Class1).GetConstructor( BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                   null, new Type[] { typeof(Int64) }, null )
                                  ?.Invoke( new object[] { 64 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try `var myClass = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(MyClass));` This api does not use any constructor so it does not have any constructor requirements.